# What is scientific in the social sciences?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Examples for natural sciences: physics, chemistry, astronomy, geology.

Social sciences: psychology, sociology, criminology, psychiatry, 
political science, human geography, demography, economics, history, anthropology, archaeology, etc.

**Natural science** has:

- very good mathematical *laws*
- algorithms to predict phenomena based on solid theories.

**Social science**:

- follows the scientific model in lab reports
- based on *hypothesising* general theories.

Is social science actually a science even despite the differences in the sue of some of the core elements of natural sciences? If so, should it be called something else other than science?

Comment: Is there a question in here? Is the question the one in the title? Also, if the question is in the title I'm not sure what the body of your question is. Is that your answer? I'm not sure what you're after here so some clarification would be nice. As it stands it seems like you're trying to solicit discussion.

Comment: Hey Dennis, yes the question is the one in the title. I am just unsure if my body is correct. I am not seeking a discussion, but more of a second opinion of the question in the title. I obviously have my perspective, but am unsure it it is widely accepted. I hope this clears up your concerns.

Comment: Is there any chance you might be able to formulate this somewhat more neutrally and proportionately? It seems unnecessarily pejorative and reductive to start from the position that the human sciences aren't science.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's a valid question and I think the answer is "not really, not across the board anyway", but approaching it with more tact and attention to detail (especially the detail of the requirements for something to be science which is _not_ logically that you find mathematical laws) is the best chance for learning something or coming to a solid conclusion.  It _is_ true that finding mathematical laws is a great way of preventing social pressures from overriding the requirement for evidence to fit well with a theory (and to show when there is more to do), but it's not the _only_ way.

Comment: I added a vote for re-opening. Although I still think the question is a bit hard to answer, at least now it isn't a leading question (at least not as much).

Comment: Just to try to be clear -- I do think the general subject is interesting, I just think there are a lot more specific and constructive concerns we can pose here relating to it.

Comment: I also think that the subject is interesting. The OP's author, unfortunately, hasn't logged in for a few months. Any takers with enough reputation to edit and resucitate the question?